# error message [localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it, Timeout: 30s,

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

MongoDb atlas connetion issue.

Can anyone know how to resolve it?

> error message [localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could
> be made because the target machine actively refused it, Timeout: 30s,
> Topology Description:

I checked MongoDB atlas connection, connection working fine, cluster running.

Comment: I suspect you don't have Atlas running on localhost, what connection string are you using?

Comment: MongoDB Atlas is a **cloud** service, certainly it does not run on your local machine **localhost**